# Why can't I fetch the stock of ahold delaize from yahoo finance API?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

My simple python code is:

```
import yfinance as yf

print(yf.Ticker('AD.AS').info)
```

AS.AD is the sign for Ahold Delaize (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AD.AS?p=AD.AS&.tsrc=fin-srch).

Sadly if I execute this command I get the following json:

```
{'logo_url': ''}
```

I've tested the code with other stocks, these did work.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong or if this is an known issue, I would be grateful if you shared it with me!

Answer (score 0):

The string for the exchange and ticker symbol are reversed on your code

Change it to this and it will work:

```
import yfinance as yf

print(yf.Ticker('AD.AS').info)
```

Comment: Oh I see that I typed it wrongly in this post, sadly AD.AS also doesn’t seem to work.